# Passing info and NotificationCenter in Cocos2d-x 3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm posting notifications in my Cocos2d-x 3.0 iOS app like this:

```
Dictionary *d = Dictionary::create();
d->setObject(Integer::create(123), "someKey");
NotificationCenter::getInstance()->postNotification(someNotification, d);
```

This works. However, I receive warnings about `Dictionary` and `Integer` being deprecated. What's the preferred, non-deprecated way to pass information with a notification in Cocos2d-x 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

The replacement for Dictionary in v3 is cocos2d::Map

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2alpha0/de/d5c/classcocos2d_1_1_map.html

Comment: How to pass a cocos2d::Map with the notification? Looks like `postNotification` requires a `Ref*` as the second argument.

Comment: Look at Ref: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0rc0/df/d28/classcocos2d_1_1_ref.html

Comment: yes, I see that many classes inherit `Ref`. However, I didn't see `Map` in there. I need help w/ the syntax for passing a `Map` along with the notification.